# Reliability standard via relative standard error for computer science or randomized algorithms

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, standard-error, algorithms

I am performing experiments on randomized algorithms, and want to do it scientifically sound.

What relative standard error of mean (RSEM) is acceptable? I know that often RSEM<30% or RSEM<25% is used, but does that also apply for randomized algorithms?

What paper/book can I cite that give a reliability standard? This would optimally be a standard for the field of computer science or randomized algorithms, but a general reliability standard would be fine, too.

---

Details: I only found

- http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/statnt/statnt24.pdf, which unfortunately is only for the health sector;
- http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=1360212642214424308&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 covering statistics for randomized algorithms, but it unfortunately does not mention standard errors.

Comment: This is a question for a different forum, I think, because "reliability" is a matter of the application and its sensitivity to errors, timing, or whatever else you use to measure reliability.  It is not a matter of statistics or data analysis.  Accordingly it would be surprising to find any general standard adopted within a broad field like computer science: that would be at best irresponsible and at worst dangerous.  (Contemplate the consequences of using a generic standard for benchmarking real-time medical applications, for instance.)

Comment: Nice example, whuber. I agree that one fixed threshold makes little sense for a large field. On the other hand, the health sector is a general field too, and there is the overview document I cited that lists several reliability standards depending on specific domains. So maybe there is something similar for computer science or randomized algorithms?

Comment: Should this post be migrated to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?